# Changing file permissions on 10.6.8 after restore

Tags: restore, permission, root

A friend has a Macbook Pro that had the drive crash.  A new hard drive was installed in the system and the OS was reinstalled.  However, when they restored from their backup (using Retrospect), the User profile folder and system sub-folders all were restored with their original permissions.

So in the User folder, is an "Ash Williams" folder and an "Ash" folder.  And in each of those folders are: Documents, Downloads, Applications, etc.  Since the permissions were restored, the duplicate folders can't be deleted or renamed.

I figure I can enable root and then delete/change the extra folders or I can boot to single user mode and the do a chmod on them, but I wanted to get the collective opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable with chmod commands, (as an administrator user) right click on the folder with the incorrect permission and choose "Properties". Then under "Sharing and Permissions" click on the Settings wheel button and select "Choose new owner..." and enter the new owner's name (you may need to "Apply to enclosed items..." too)

Answer (score 1):

Just launch Terminnal.app and delete the duplicate folder using:

```
sudo rm -rf "/Users/Joe Duplicate"
```

WARNING! **DO NOT FORGET THE QUOTES**. This is especially important in your case because you could accidentally delete the wrong Ash folder.